# Answering Wie alt bist du?

Tags: question, idiomaticity

Can we respond by

> Ich *habe* zweiundzwanzig Jahre alt.

?

I know that you can answer by

> Ich *bin* zweiundzwanzig Jahre alt.

Which answer is more idiomatic correct.

Comment: why would the first sentence be an option?

Comment: You have probably French or a simiklar langauge as your mother tongue? Because in French you would say (J'ai vingt-deux ans - Ich habe zweiundzwanzig Jahre alt.). The common wy to say it correct, is your second option

Comment: The verb in the question ("wie alt **bist** du?") implies that the same verb must be in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Ich habe zweiundzwanzig Jahre alt* is wrong.

In colloquial language you may say *Ich habe zweiundzwanzig Jahre [auf dem Buckel](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/etwas_auf_dem_Buckel_haben)* (I have 22 years on the hunchback).

But the correct version is: "Ich **bin** zweiundzwanzig Jahre alt."

Comment: It even becomes more obvious when you leave out the detail: *ich bin () alt*

Comment: @Burki: That is not a good indicator, given that languages that *do* use "to have" with respect to an exact age, such as French ("J'ai 22 ans.") would still use "to be" to express (unspecific) age: "Je suis vieux."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper but french does not have *vieux* in *J'ai xy ans*.

Answer (score 2):

Well, even though I think the question is already answered, I'd like to share some thoughts and additions:

For the question:

> Wie alt bist du?

The (direct) answer would be a number, but now it depends on how you would answer:
If you want to say "I'm 21 years old.", you see in English it's the same verb (*to be* = *sein*), and you answer by telling your actual age. So, you could say:

> Ich bin 21 Jahre alt.
> Ich bin 21.
> 21 Jahre.

But if you, for example, answered "So far I lived (have lived) 21 years!", the emphasis is not on (only) your actual age and could be on some additional information you'd like to tell in your answer or dialog, so I might say the answer is somehow indirect!

Then you can use *haben*; for example, one could say:

> Ich habe 21 Jahr auf dem Buckel (as @knut quoted).
> Ich habe 21 Jahre hinter mir.  (but this sounds also as if he was expecting to die as @Iris commented)
>
> Ich habe lange gelebt. (Looking back on a good or long life.)
> Ich habe noch viele Jahre vor mir. (Looking forward to a long life.)
> Ich habe gut gelebt. (Looking back on a good life and maybe expecting a near death.)

Comment: I wouldn't recomment to say "Ich habe 21 Jahre hinter mir". That sounds like: "Ich habe mein Leben hinter mir" and that you are ready to die in peace.

Comment: "Ich bin 21 Jahre jung"

Comment: @Reese stimmt die Antwort kam irgendwann in mode!

Answer (score 0):

Reading the questions and the answers I noticed a key bit of information that may be the clue to handling this.

In French one says:

> J’ai {…} *ans.*

Which can be shortened to:

> I have {…} *years.*

Essentially you are quantifying the number of years you ‘own’. Likewise probably for all romance languages e.g. Italian.

The Germanic languages, however, say:

> Ich *bin* {…} alt.
>
> I *am* {…} old.

Essentially, one states the age with an adjective and further specifies the *adjective* with the number of years. Since we are adding an adjective, it only makes sense to do so with the copular verb. Likewise probably for all Germanic languages.

Those constructions would probably have been the etymologically oldest and any shortenings happened later when the verb usage had already been established; it then made sense to stick to the verb.

Any German constructions using *haben* always will depict a place where the years can be *had* or *kept* (one’s back or the area behind one) or use an additional verb which uses *haben* in the perfect tense.

---

I assume but cannot prove that this hypothesis can be generalised. It at least works for Finnish, where you say:

> Minä olen {…} *vanha.*
>
> I am {…} *old.*